# Passing parentheses to command in bash function

Tags: bash, macos

I'd like to make a function, like this, in my bash profile.

```
postfix_log() {
    log stream --predicate (process == "smtpd") || (process == "smtp") --info
}
```

Bash hates that.

> -bash: /Users/me/.bash_profile: line 112: syntax error near unexpected token `('

> -bash: /Users/me/.bash_profile: line 112: `postfix_log() {'

I've also tried putting that into an alias.

`alias postfix_log="log stream --predicate (process == 'smtpd') || (process == 'smtp') --info"`

But, when I run that alias, `log` can't understand the command.

> log: Bad predicate (Unable to parse the format string "(process"): (process
> -bash: (process: command not found

How can I use parentheses in a bash function as arguments to a command?

Comment: let me know if this works: try modifying the function to `log stream --predicate '(process == "smtpd") || (process == "smtp")' --info`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the filter expression, to tell the shell to pass it as a literal argument to the `log` command rather than trying to parse it as shell syntax (which is what causes the error).

```
log stream --predicate '(process == "smtpd") || (process == "smtp")' --info
```

Note that `--predicate` and `--info` aren't part of the expression, so they shouldn't be included in the quoted section.

(BTW, the [`man` page for the `log` command](https://manpagez.com/man/1/log/) includes several examples showing how to quote the expression.)

Comment: and so it does. Thank you either way.